# Form fields in array uniquely identified with item Id - how to access their values in the controller?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have this dynamically created form:

```
<form>
    Item #1 <input type="text" name="qty" id="Item_3223" value="3">
    Item #2 <input type="text" name="qty" id="Item_2243" value="1">
    Item #3 <input type="text" name="qty" id="Item_5328" value="1">
    Item #4 <input type="text" name="qty" id="Item_3250" value="5">
    <!--... and so on...-->
    <button type="submit">Update quantities</button>
</form>
```

The fields are generated server side like this:

```
<input type="text" name="qty" id="Item_@item.Id" value="@item.Qty">
```

In my controller, how can I receive the array and perform an update on each of the items in it?

Simplified, my `Update`-method looks like this now:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(IFormCollection form)
{
    var updateItem = new ShoppingCartItem();
    foreach (string item in form.Keys)
    {
        updateItem = (from c in _context.ShoppingCartItems
        where (c.ShoppingCartId == ShoppingCartItem.ShoppingCartId &&
            c.ProductId == form.[what goes here?])
        select c).FirstOrDefault();
        updateItem.Quantity = form.[what goes here?]
    }
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cart");
}
```

Since I can't know the name of the `form.Keys`, how can I extract the values from them? I seem to remember this was quite easy in classic ASP back in the day ...

**Edit**

With help from @David, I put this together:

```
<input asp-for="@item.Quantity" name="Item_@item.ProductId" id="Item_@item.ProductId" />
```

... and:

```
var updateItem = new ShoppingCartItem();
int qty = 0;
int pId = 0;
foreach (string item in form.Keys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("Item_")))
{
    pId = int.Parse(item.Replace("Item_", ""));
    updateItem = (from c in _context.ShoppingCartItems
                  where (c.ShoppingCartId == ShoppingCartItem.ShoppingCartId && c.ProductId == pId)
                  select c).FirstOrDefault();
    qty = int.Parse(form[item]);
    updateItem.Quantity = qty;
}
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Works like a charm! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing an array to the server-side code.  You're passing a single value with the name `"qty"`.  This would likely be the *last* instance of that input in your form.

An *array* needs brackets in the `name`:

```
<input type="text" name="qty[]" id="Item_@item.Id" value="@item.Qty">
```

Then in the server-side code the "key" for the array is `"qty[]"`.  You can pull that array from the `form` object and iterate over it for your needs:

```
var inputArray = form["qty[]"];
```

Basically, all you need is the brackets in the `name` to tell the browser that these multiple elements constitute an array of values.  The `id` has nothing to do with form posting.

**Edit:** If you *do* need that "id" value, then you can put it in the `name`:

```
<input type="text" name="Item_@item.Id" id="Item_@item.Id" value="@item.Qty">
```

*Then* you would have multiple unique key/value pairs in the form post, which you can check as you're currently attempting to (`foreach (string item in form.Keys)`) and then parse out the "id" from that `item` string as needed.

Comment: I don't get it - If I need the Id's (I think I do, because I have to update the database on the Id with the quantity), then how should the input field look? `name="Item_@item.Id[]" id="Item_@item.Id"` probably won't work?

Comment: @Stian: Well, no, that wouldn't work because `item.Id` likely isn't an array.  Which of the options I suggest depends on whether you want a single *array* of values (with no identifiers), or a collection of multiple key/value pairs (where the key contains the identifier in your data).  The text of the question uses the term "array", but from the usage it looks like you actually want multiple key/value pairs.  Which would be the second suggestion I edited into the answer.  In that case the `name` attribute would need to be unique in order for the browser to send all of the fields to the server.

Comment: I thought so. So how do I extract the key name and value in the foreach in the controller? Here: `c.ProductId == item.*whatHere?*` and here: `updateItem.Quantity = item.*whatHere?*;`.

Comment: @Stian: When you do `foreach (string item in form.Keys)`, within that loop the `item` variable should be what was constructed from `Item_@item.Id`.  So you can use `item` to pull the value from the form: `var value = form[item];`.  Then you can do some string manipulation on `item` to get your data identifier.  Something like: `var id = int.Parse(item.Replace("Item_", ""));`  This is all free-hand and untested of course, but the concepts are all there.  If you pause the debugger and example `item` and `form[item]` that should give you some useful info.

Comment: I got the correct data now, except there is a Key-Value pair called _RequestVerificationToken, which is sent along with my form data. That causes a FormatException when I try to `int.Parse(item)`. From what I can tell, it's always the last pair. How should I deal with that? Maybe loop through the collection's length -1?

Comment: @Stian: I wouldn't assume the collection length, but perhaps filter on strings matching `"Item_*"` instead.  Something like: `foreach (string item in form.Keys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("Item_")))`  If that doesn't do the trick, an `if` block within the loop can get the same result.  You basically just want to ignore any keys which don't match your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is a dictionary. For that, you'd need inputs like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="qty[0].Key" value="@item.Id" />
<input type="text" name="qty[0].Value" value="@item.Qty" />
```

You'd bind that to a param like `Dictionary<int, int> qty`. Then, you can access the quantities for each item via something like:

```
item.Qty = qty[item.Id];
```

That said, it's usually better to just use view models for this kind of thing, so you can bind to properties in a strongly-typed way. For example, you could use something like:

```
public class ItemQuantityViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can have as the model for your form (and the param you bind to on your action) be `List<ItemQuantityViewModel>`. Finally, you'd just have input like:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id">
    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Qty">
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems simpler than the answer I accepted, but I'm too lazy to change everything, now that I finally got it working with the key-values. Maybe I will use the viewmodel solution in v2.0. :)